# Retrieve SQL Server database from old Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows, copy, backup

I have just changed my Windows. In the old SQL Server, I had some important databases and I want to find and copy them to new installed windows and SQL Server.

How can I find and copy old databases from old windows and copy them to new SQL Server?

> P.S: Actually, my I have changed my hard disk and all of the old files
>   is located on my old hard drive and I want to find and copy the old
>   server from old hard drive to new drive.

Comment: Just restore the database from your last backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either backup the prior database or detach the database .mdf (data) and .ldf (log) file and reattach via http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/24/sql-server-2005-t-sql-script-to-attach-and-detach-database/
or
Backup your database and restore. Six of one, half dozen of the other.

```
-- Step 1 : Detach Database using following script
USE [master]
 GO
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks',
@keepfulltextindexfile = N'true'
GO
-- Step 2 : Move Data files and Log files to new location
 -- Do this step and move to Step 3
 --  Step 3 : Attach Database using following script
USE [master]
 GO
CREATE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Data\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf' ),
 ( FILENAME = N'C:\Data\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
 GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT name
FROM MASTER.sys.databases sd
WHERE name = N'AdventureWorks'
AND SUSER_SNAME(sd.owner_sid) = SUSER_SNAME() )
EXEC [AdventureWorks].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame=N'sa',
@map=false
 GO
```

[Create a Full Database Backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

There are other options as well (Red Gate tools, Visual Studio Tools, etc)

Comment: Thank you, but you know, the problem is that I don't know where is the old backup to restore. I have the folders and applications of the old server in my windows.old directory.

Comment: Ok then look for the .mdf files or .bak files

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure your database engine is running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx). Connect to your old server using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and [backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) the database. Then transfer the backup file to the new system and restore the backup using SSMS again.

Comment: Just do not forget that, you cannot restore SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2012 / 2014 directly, you need to restore it to 2005 or 2008 first, change the compability mode, take another backup and restore it to 2012 / 2014. 
And also you may need to remediate some of your Views, SPs, UDFs to make them compatible with 2012 / 2014.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that I don't know where is old backup and how to connect to the old server.